# Issue in appending and storing the elements in 2d int array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an issue in adding an array elements and store it into a 2d int array.

An example,

I have a 2d `int array(newint2d[][])` which contains 2 elements initially.

```
0101100000010111101

0011100110111100110
```

In each iteration will be getting 2 elements.

The looping condition (5times) will produce 10 elements like this randomly at the end of looping statements.

For each iteration i need to add the 2 elements with next 2 and again next 2 like that in 5th iteration i should append the last 2 elements to the 8 elements.

So that i will get 10 elements at final iteration.

And that should store in the 2d int array newint2d[][] in this.

Finally the 2d int array (`newint2d[][]`) or new 2d int array should contains all the 10 elements stored in it.

For Eg:

```
**0011100000010111101**

**0101100110111100110**                                 I iteration



*0011100000010111101*

*0101100110111100110*                                    II iteration



0011100000010111101

0101100110111100110

0011100110110111101

0101100000011100110

0101100000010111101

0011100110111100110
```

How to solve this problem?

If there is something i didn't explain well or you need more code to understand the question let me know.

Comment: Arrays have a fixed size in Java. Use a `List` to easily add elements.

Comment: post your code you tried......

Comment: Instead of all those 0's and 1's, can you put the code you used to generate it? @August is correct, though. The List data structure will dynamically resize itself unlike an array which has a fixed dimension when you create it.

Comment: can you provide me the snippet how to add by using List? Each time i need to add the 2d int[][] array which has 2elements. So at 5th iteration i can have 10 elements.